# Angular 8, Component not loading in HTML when condition is getting true

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am facing a strange issue now which was working before. I am using Angular 8. Please see this.

App.component.ts

```
constructor(private readonly oidcFacade: OidcFacade) {
    this.loading$ = this.oidcFacade.loading$;
    this.expiring$ = this.oidcFacade.expiring$;
    this.expired$ = this.oidcFacade.expired$;
    this.loggedIn$ = this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$;
    this.errors$ = this.oidcFacade.errors$;
    this.identity$ = this.oidcFacade.identity$;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.oidcFacade.getOidcUser();

    this.oidcFacade.getUserManager().getUser().then( user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('Analytics Logged In');
        console.log('this.loggedIn$', this.loggedIn$);
      } else {
        this.oidcFacade.signinRedirect();
      }
    });
  }
```

I am using OIDC Client for authentication purposes. For the first time, when the user is not logged in, it redirects for authentication, gets token and comes back. This process makes this.loggedIn$ and other objects to be instantiated.

App.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loggedIn$ | async;">
  <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #notLoggedIn>
  <app-progress-spinner
    [color]="color" [mode]="mode"
    [value]="value" [diameter]="diameter">
  </app-progress-spinner>
</ng-template>
```

This will show a Material loading icon till authentication gets completed and loggedIn variable will be true and app-dashboard will be rendered.

Let's say this code is on a menu called /dashboard and If I keep my application for idle sometimes and go back on another menu and come back on /dashboard, it keeps showing app-progress-spinner.

An important point to note is that console prints **"Analytics Logged In"** and object with this.loggedIn which only gets true when authentication is completed.
If I check the console and elements section, it only shows app-progress-spinner component but not the app-dashboard.

Any ideas? It is strange. It works sometimes and sometimes I only get the loading icon.

Is it because of Angular 8 or something else I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try turn `Ivy Renderer` off, it's yet bugged, and caused for me in another situations similar problems. Inside tsconfig.app.json `"angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": true }`. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Sure, I will give it a try. By default, I did not have these settings in my tsconfig.json.That means it was building it enableIvy as off.

Comment: please post code where you are setting value in `this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$`

Comment: you don't set any value. OIDC Client library automatically does that once authentication is complete. It works by default if you keep using the application. If you keep it idle and change tabs and come back to this tab code, the loading icon appears.

Comment: Okey, So can you try to subscribe to the observable, and check if values are coming properly in console. in ngOnInit `this.loggedIn$.subscribe(status => console.log(status))`. what are the values getting populated in console?

Comment: Yes. it is printing proper value post-authentication. For component TS files, it is printing correct values and inside "Analytics Logged In". For View HTML part, it is still showing a loading icon that means false condition.

Comment: I think somehow async part working/not working intermittently.

Comment: can you please post what are the values that are printing in console?

Comment: You are logging `this.loggedIn$`.  I want to see values after subscription `this.loggedIn$.subscribe(status => console.log(status))`

Comment: this.loggedIn$.subscribe(status => console.log(status)) will print false always but because this line this.loggedIn$ = this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$; where this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$; gets true after authentication, should update this.loggedIn | async automatically... Am i correct ?

Comment: No, your code will only work if you are able to obtain the true false value in subscription. this is just test. If this always returns false then your `async` will never work.

Comment: @Plochie Code is working fine each and every time even for this.loggedIn prints false and it is loading app-dashboard also. The issue is occurring only when you keep it idle and change tabs and come back on the same tab. To test it where it is printing this.oidcFacade.loggedIn as true after authentication, I have replaced same in HTML also. as oidcFacade.loggedIn | async. Let's see if it works.

Comment: @Plochie, even using this.oidcFacade.loggedIn in HTML which is getting "true" also not working. It prints true in console. It even prints true in HTML while I am printing it through {{ oidcFacade.loggedIn | async }}, it prints true but still shows the loading icon and unable to load app-dashboard. If you check Console Elements HTML, it shows app-progress-spinner but not the app-dashboard. Note: The issue is occurring only when the app is idle for some time ( let's say 10-15 mins) and when you change the tabs. Strange right?

Comment: As per explanation is looks strange. Can u provide minimal stackblitz. It will be much easier to work with the code.

Comment: @Plochie thank you for help. I solved the issue. Please refer to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Seems like the issue is with the latest downloaded angular core files that are being mentioned in package.json.

By default, all files were with ^ cap and ~ attached with the library versions in package.json.

My earlier code looked like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^8.1.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "oidc-client": "1.8.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
```

I removed all ^ and ~ from versions. It will allow telling Angular to download the mentioned specific version library only while ^ and ~ allow angular to download the next minor patch versions.

I am not sure but somehow downloaded patch versions might be causing the issue. I changed it to this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "8.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "8.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "8.1.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "8.1.0",
    "core-js": "2.6.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "2.2.0",
    "oidc-client": "1.8.2",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
```

Similarly, I did for core devdependencies library also.

Thank you.